R code works put not python version big query
I have some code for pulling some data in Big query but the python version of it throws an error message. I know the python code is correct, and I have all of the packages I need but I keep getting the following error message:

PermissionDenied: 403 request failed: the user does not have 'bigquery.readsessions.create' permission for 'project_name'

The purpose is for a user to be able to access the information with a key instead of having to have individual user access. Again, it executes perfectly in R but I need it to do the same thing with python. Here are the two versions of the code:
R code
if (!requireNamespace("bigrquery", quietly = TRUE)) {
install.packages("bigrquery")
}
library(bigrquery)

# Authenticate using a service account key
project <- "project_name"
keyfile <- "C:/Users/jay/Docs/Query/project_name.json"
bigrquery::bq_auth(path = keyfile)
con <- DBI::dbConnect(bigquery(), project = " project_name ")
# Define the query
query <- "
SELECT *
FROM ` project_name.angel.info`
"

# Execute the query and store results in a data frame
out <- DBI::dbGetQuery(con, query)
out <-as.data.frame(out)

Python code
#packages
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import db_dtypes
import pandas as pd
import json

# Authenticate using a service account key
project_id = " project_name "
keyfile_path = " C:/Users/jay/Docs/Query/project_name.json "

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(keyfile_path)
client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials, project=project_id)

# Define the query
query = """
SELECT *
FROM ` project_name.angel.info `
"""
# Execute the query and store results in a DataFrame
query_job = client.query(query)
results = query_job.result()
df = results.to_dataframe()

# Display the DataFrame
print(df)


Check project name carefully in Python. Does it match in R? You redact here but be sure no extra whitespaces are included in project name and key path.

Can't see your service account json, but it's possible you need to add the apis to scopes in the json. Last line in example below includes it for Drive, GCP, and Bigquery.
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "projectid",
  "private_key_id": "xxxx",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----",
  "client_email": "serviceaccount.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "xxxxx",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/xxxxx",
  "scopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery"]
}

